# How to remove white screen before loading of first activity in android?

Tags: android

Whenever i launch my app, a white screen appears in the beginning with the title bar. I don't want this screen to be appear in my app. I have read previous questions, but answers are not clear to me.

I'm also using splash screen, but white screen appears before that.

I don't want to change the theme style, because it either increases the minimum sdkVersion or changes the style of edittext, buttons, checkboxes etc

Please help me to keep me out of this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Preface**: For questions like this you should post your starting activities xml and the `onCreate()` and associated methods.

When android starts your application it will typically use a black view to indicate that it is launching, this my change to white with your theme/style selected.  If you are loading the view correctly then you should only see this blank (white or black) page for 50-200 ms (I can't find the google document for this right now).  If you are doing a lot of work in your `onCreate` method then it will take longer.

Typically to make my views display faster I will simply do the majority of the linking work after it has loaded.  ex:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.initial_activity_layout);

    //We use a handler so that the activity starts very fast
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            delayedInit();
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Additionally, mobile applications should typically not have a splash screen unless they take quite a while to load the contents (e.g. games, first time launch files, etc.) and should not be used *just* to brand your application, or display your company name.

**Update (July 31, 2015)**

Google apps are now moving in the direction of having splash screens (see drive, GMail, etc.)

Additionally,  You shouldn't be doing any work other than de-referencing views in the  onCreate() method.  Any long running operations such as retrieving information from memory (database, prefs, etc.) should be done in an AsyncTaskLoader or AsyncTask.

Comment: well thanks for this...

but its not working as i want..:(

not satisfied..:|

Comment: How long do you see the white page?  If it is only for the 50-200 ms then there is nothing that you can do about it.  Unlike iOS, Android doesn't use launch images since the activities should start fairly quickly.

Comment: actually it depends on RAM memory. If there is enough RAM free, then it took less time to load and white screen appears for only 100-200 ms. But if free RAM is less than 200 mb, then it takes 2-3 secs to load, and hence white screen appears for same time.

Comment: Try not to confuse correlation with causation.  You application by default on Android devices will be given about 24-32mb of RAM.  The fact that more RAM is available is linked to the amount of background applications/services meaning that with more free RAM there are less processes fighting for CPU time.  If it truly takes that long to load then you are probably not waiting long enough, try increasing the delayed time until you see your background showing through quickly every time.

Comment: i know this fact...but i cant change the user's free RAM. So, I need a method to disappear white screen of my application

Comment: If you can post your `onCreate` method (with the associated methods) and the XML Layout for your activity then I will be able to help a little more.  In the end though, there will always be a short period where you will see the white (or black) screen --due to Androids implementation.

Comment: what is  delayedInit() method and what u have written in it is it short or long code please correct if i am wrong ...

Comment: @Vidhyanand: First of all, sorry for the late response.  The `delayedInit()` method is the method that contains the setup code you would like to perform.  This should only be used if you are running a lot of setup code that interferes with a quick startup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AppCompatActivity then create below theme in style.xml :

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

And in manifest file for SplashActivity add theme :

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add below line in your Theme of splash screen as you wrote you are using splash screen**

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

Answer (score -1):

1- Make windowDisablePreview false in your style.xml

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">false</item>
```

2- Add windowBackground in your  style.xml.

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/your_background</item>
```